# Logar em site utilizando satellizer.js

Tags: api, oauth2, token

preciso fazer uma aplicação em que o usuário possa se logar através do facebook e soundcloud, e encontrei esse https://github.com/sahat/satellizer para fazer isso,  e segundo essa pagina https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/issues/3 é possível fazer isso com o soundcloud por oAuth2, porém não consigo de jeito, creio que esteja muito perto da solução, pois ao utilizar esse código:

index.html

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary md-hue-2 btn-soundcloud" ng-click="authenticate('soundcloud')"></md-button>
```

controller.js

```
   .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $auth) {
       $scope.authenticate = function(provider) {
         $auth.authenticate(provider);
       };
  });
```

config.js

```
    $authProvider.oauth2({
      name: 'soundcloud',
      url: 'https://soundcloud.com/connect',
      clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
      authorizationEndpoint: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token',
      popupOptions: { width: 580, height: 400 }
    });
```

Abre uma nova janela me retornando o seguinte erro:

```
  {"errors":[{"error_message":"404 - Not Found"}]}
```

Alguém já utilizou  satellizer para logar com Soundcloud?
Ou simplesmente se puder me recomendar outro que faça a mesma coisa...

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problema, apenas alterei meu config.js para essa forma:

```
    $authProvider.oauth2({
      name: 'soundcloud',
      url: '/auth/soundcloud',
      clientId: 'CLIENT_ID',
      responseType: 'code',
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/callback.html',
      authorizationEndpoint: 'https://soundcloud.com/connect',
      popupOptions: { width: 580, height: 400 }
    });
```

Acredito que a URL que estava usando em authorizationEndpoint estava errada.